# Binding a window's property to one of its own resources in XAML?

Tags: xaml, binding

When I have a usercontrol that has a property I want bound to a resource in XAML, I generally set that binding in the control or window that contains the control. E.g:

```
<local:MyNeatControl MyProperty="{StaticResource ...}" />
```

That sets the MyProperty property of that instance of the MyNeatControl object to a resource in the parent control.

But what do I do when I have a window, and I want to bind one of its properties to one of its own resources?  It's easy enough to do in code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.MainWindow_Loaded);
    ...
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyProperty = this.Resources["MyProperty"] as MyProperty;
    ...
}
```

But this bugs me.  I'd much rather bind the property in XAML than to set it in code.

How do I do it?  I've tried adding the MyProperty declaration as an attribute to the  element. but I get an error:

```
The property 'MyProperty' was not found in type 'Window'.
```

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is of data type.

When I declare a child element, within an XAML file, that child's declaration has the type of that child. This declares an object of type MyNeatControl, and within its declaration, I can access the properties of that type:

```
<local:MyNeatControl MyProperty="{StaticResource ...}" />
```

But when I'm declaring a type, be it window or control, the type of the object, within the XAML file, is that of it's parent. This defines a MyWindow class that inherits from MyWindowBase, but within the XAML, the type in scope is MyWindowBase, **not** MyWindow:

```
<local:MyWindowBase
        x:Class="MyProject.MyWindow"
        ....
        >
    <local:MyWindowBase.Resources>
        ...
    </local:MyWindowBase.Resources>
    ...
</local:MyWindowBase>
```

So what to do?  Sidestep the problem.  Use a Style:

```
<local:MyWindowBase>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyWindow">
        <Setter Property="MyProperty" Value="{StaticResource ..}" />
    </Style>
</local:MyWindowBase>
```

This sets the "MyProperty" property of MyWindow to the specificed resource.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingToOwnResources.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="{DynamicResource WindowWidth}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <System:Double x:Key="WindowWidth">300</System:Double>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem creating the resource, I'm having a problem pointing one of the window's properties to it.

Comment: Or, rather, my problem isn't setting properties defined on Window, but of setting properties defined on MainWindow.